# Where is libintl3 and libiconv2 for gnu make on windows, needed to compile vim with ruby on MinGW

Tags: vim, makefile, mingw, gnu

I am trying to run gnu make for windows, but it wouldn't run because `libint3.dll` was not found.

Sure enough, http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm specifies that `libint3` and `libiconv2` are required, but trying to follow their link obviously generates an error on the server.

So, do I need these libraries, and where would I get them, *or*
can I download gnu make from somewhere else.

*more background*

Here's what I try to do, and maybe someone else can share a way how to do it differently altogether: I want to compilve vim with support for ruby 1.8.7 so that I can use the http://code.google.com/p/vorax/ plugin for vim. I downloaded minGW, gnuMake, ruby 1.8.7 and the vimsources and am stuck now calling (vim's) makefile `Make_ming.mak`.

I have added according tags because maybe -*just maybe*- someone else ran into the same problem.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[The gnuwin32 page at sourceforge](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/make-dep-zip.php) appears to have the dependencies you need:

```
$ unzip -l make-3.81-dep.zip
Archive:  make-3.81-dep.zip
Make-3.81: Dependencies
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
   898048  2004-03-16 12:37   bin/libiconv2.dll
   103424  2005-05-06 12:52   bin/libintl3.dll
       24  2006-11-24 16:05   manifest/make-3.81-dep.ver
       93  2006-11-24 16:05   manifest/make-3.81-dep.mft
---------                     -------
  1001589                     4 files
```

If you want a direct link, try [this](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/gnuwin32/make/3.81/make-3.81-dep.zip?r=http%3A%2F%2Fgnuwin32.sourceforge.net%2Fpackages%2Fmake.htm&ts=1295607625&use_mirror=surfnet)

Answer (score 1):

On the page you linked to (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm) there is a link to the Dependencies for make (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/make-dep-zip.php).  If you download this (I just tried it), it contains the two libraries that you're looking for.  If you have trouble with the download, try another sourceforge mirror.

---

Regarding compiling Vim, I found that the easiest way to do this is to use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com).  Install it (you'll need to select a lot of the development libraries).  Open up a bash window and enter the following.  You'll obviously want to tweak the paths to and versions of perl, python, ruby and xpm (or remove them if you don't want them).

```
USERNAME=Al USERDOMAIN= make -f Make_cyg.mak GUI=yes PERL=c:/applications/development/activeperl DYNAMIC_PERL=yes PYTHON=c:/applications/development/python25 DYNAMIC_PYTHON=yes RUBY=c:/applications/development/ruby DYNAMIC_RUBY=yes OLE=yes USEDLL=no CSCOPE=yes FEATURES=HUGE XPM=c:/applications/development/xpm PERL_VER=58 PYTHON_VER=25 RUBY_VER=18 RUBY_VER_LONG=1.8
```

I also found it was necessary (with Ruby 1.8) to edit the `ruby.h` file in `ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mswin32/config.h` and comment out the check at the start of the file that checks the MSC version (first three lines).  For XPM, you'll need the xpm library file from the XPM website and also the source files (`simx.h`, `xpm.h` and `xpm4.dll`).  `simx.h` and `xpm.h` go into the include directory and `xpm4.dll` goes into the install directory.