# libintl3.dll error while rebuilding Carla ( a driving Simulator ) on Windows 10

Tags: artificial-intelligence, game-engine, unreal-engine4, carla

**make.exe - System Error** -
*The code execution cannot proceed because libintl3.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem*

I was trying to build **CARLA** with **Unreal Engine** on Windows 10. But this error keeps popping up. How and where can I add the missing **libintl3.dll** in my system?

I did download that **.dll** from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm this link and added it *C:\Windows\System32*  here but no improvement.

Here is the link to how to install **CARLA**. http://carla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how_to_build_on_windows/

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution link --
 [Where is libintl3 and libiconv2 for gnu make on windows, needed to compile vim with ruby on MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757911/where-is-libintl3-and-libiconv2-for-gnu-make-on-windows-needed-to-compile-vim-w)

**Solution**---Download the dependencies and paste them in the path of **make.exe**

Here is the link for the dependencies
 https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/make/3.81/make-3.81-dep.zip/download?use_mirror=kent&r=http%3A%2F%2Fgnuwin32.sourceforge.net%2Fpackages%2Fmake.htm&use_mirror=surfnet